# Looping Multiple variables using R

Tags: r, loops

I imported data from a CSV file and wanted to create a "Comparison table" between two prices of a company's stock in 2018:

```
Table2018<-data.frame("Comparison"= c("Opening Price bigger than Adjusted Closing Price",
"Opening Pricee smaller than Adjusted Closing Price","Total trading days"),
"January18","February18",
"March18","April18","May18","June18","July18"
,"August18","September18","October18",
"November18","December18",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I have this set of code (all comparisons):

```
Table2018[1,2]<-sum(January18$Opening.Price > January18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,3]<-sum(February18$Opening.Price > February18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,4]<-sum(March18$Opening.Price > March18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,5]<-sum(April18$Opening.Price > April18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,6]<-sum(May18$Opening.Price > May18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,7]<-sum(June18$Opening.Price > June18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,8]<-sum(July18$Opening.Price > July18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,9]<-sum(August18$Opening.Price > August18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,10]<-sum(September18$Opening.Price > September18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,11]<-sum(October18$Opening.Price > October18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,12]<-sum(November18$Opening.Price > November18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
Table2018[1,13]<-sum(December18$Opening.Price > December18$Adjusted.Closing.Price)
```

For those who asked, this is the final code part and my poor looking table:

```
Total.trading.days <- c(length(January18$ן..Date),length(February18$ן..Date),length(March18$ן..Date),length(April18$ן..Date),length(May18$ן..Date),length(June18$ן..Date),length(July18$ן..Date),length(August18$ן..Date),length(September18$ן..Date),length(October18$ן..Date),length(November18$ן..Date),length(December18$ן..Date))

#Displaying finished table
for (i in 1:12) {
  Table2018[3,i+1]<-Total.trading.days[i]
  Table2018[2,i+1]<-Total.trading.days[i]-as.numeric(Table2018[1,i+1])
}
Table2018

                                          Comparison
1   Opening Price bigger than Adjusted Closing Price
2 Opening Pricee smaller than Adjusted Closing Price
3                                 Total trading days
  X.January18. X.February18. X.March18. X.April18.
1           20            17         17         13
2            1             1          1          4
3           21            18         18         17
  X.May18. X.June18. X.July18. X.August18.
1       19        18        14          18
2        1         0         2           2
3       20        18        16          20
  X.September18. X.October18. X.November18.
1              8           17            19
2              3            2             0
3             11           19            19
  X.December18.
1            16
2             4
3            20

dput(head(Table2018))

structure(list(Comparison = c("Opening Price bigger than Adjusted Closing Price", 
"Opening Pricee smaller than Adjusted Closing Price", "Total trading days"
), X.January18. = c("20", "1", "21"), X.February18. = c("17", 
"1", "18"), X.March18. = c("17", "1", "18"), X.April18. = c("13", 
"4", "17"), X.May18. = c("19", "1", "20"), X.June18. = c("18", 
"0", "18"), X.July18. = c("14", "2", "16"), X.August18. = c("18", 
"2", "20"), X.September18. = c("8", "3", "11"), X.October18. = c("17", 
"2", "19"), X.November18. = c("19", "0", "19"), X.December18. = c("16", 
"4", "20")), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

1. The problem main  is that this is too much code. In the second part of the code, how can i make a nice loop? do i need one?
2. Why do i get in the table's headline this format: `X.month.` ?
3. I would love to have tips on how to present my table more beautifully as well

Comment: show the table you are looping through and the results (for just a few rows manual is fine) and you will get a better answer

Comment: Try to avoid for loops in R at all costs. Use apply functions instead. It makes your code so much simpler

Comment: Your question does not require any for loops btw. I assume you have 12 dataframes of two columns (Closing and Opening price) for each month and you would like to get a new df with the sum of the values where opening is greater than closing?

Comment: Thank you all. i edited my Q. i have a table with 4 rows and 13 columns (including headlines). note that i'm new to R and a non native english speaker

Comment: Can you show your actual dataframe (or the first lines) with dput(head(Table2018))?

Comment: I added the output of the code you provided. hope this is what you wanted to see. let me know if not. sorry in advance i am so new to this.